# Not getting value from my xml response

Tags: jquery, ajax, xml

I am trying to get a value from an XML response, but I'm getting a NULL value.
What am I doing wrong?

```js
$.ajax({
  method: "GET",
  url: "fphub01-prd.tc.workstreaminc.com/hub/custLookup/";,
  data: {
    emailAddress: email
  }
}).done(function(msg) {
  xmlDoc = $.parseXML(data); //console.log(msg); alert( "Data Saved: " + xmlDoc );
});
```

I have seen an XML response in the console, like this:

```
jquery.min.js (line 4)
Params Headers Response XML
```

```xml
<wstm:PublicResponse xmlns:wstm="http://schemas.workstreaminc.com/platform" emailAddress="ABarnum@workstreaminc.com">
    <wstm:customerHost custId="fphub01" hostId="fphub01" hostUrl="fphub01-prd.tc.workstreaminc.com" />
</wstm:PublicResponse>
```

But I want to get the `URL` and `custID` from the XML response.

Comment: Please edit your question instead of commenting in extra information.

Comment: There's an extraneous semicolon after the `url` in your AJAX call. Is that just a copy/paste typo?

Comment: I don't see how you are trying to get the value. Was parsing successful? How do you use xmlDoc afterwards?

Answer (score 0):

Why not consider using PHP?

The code below will display all data from the sample API XML response (the url). Using `simplexml_load_file()`, interprets the XML data into an object. Which then you can use it.

```
<?php

$html = "";

$url = "http://demo.cakemarketing.com/api/1/get.asmx/Advertisers?api_key=dNJFmId9rI";

$xml = simplexml_load_file($url);

for($i = 0; $i < count($xml);$i++){

      echo $xml->Advertiser[$i]->advertiser_name."<br/>";

}

?>
```

[more details](http://unselfishideas.blogspot.com/2015/09/get-api-xml-response-data-with-php.html)